# Remove Rejected Button in Approving Workflow SharePoint 2013

Tags: approval-process

I want to hide Rejected, Revise, and the other button in Approving Workflow SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to create a new outcome option. I used this [site](http://sivarajan.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Designer-Workflow-Creating-a-Custom-Task-Outcome-Part-3) when I ran into a similar issue.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Mr Magean.

I will try that option.

Regards,
Galih